# Why is clang-tidy giving me an uninitialized error for this c++ code?

Tags: c++, initialization, indexoutofboundsexception

I don't understand why there is a problem with my code. I've made sure to initialize every value in my 2D array, so there shouldn't be an uninitialized value error anywhere!

Note: I cannot use `std::vector` for this project. I'm also using different functions instead of `std::min` because I'm not allowed to import `algorithm` for this project.

This is the error reported by clang-tidy:

> 2nd function call argument is an uninitialized value

Here is my code (error only occurs on line 17):

```
int** SeamCarver::CarvingSeamVertical() const {
  int** energies = new int*[height_];
  for (unsigned int row = 0; row < height_; row++) {
    energies[row] = new int[width_];
    for (unsigned int col = 0; col < width_; col++) {
      energies[row][col] = 0; // initializes every value in the 2D array to zero
    }
  }
  for (unsigned int col = 0; col < width_; col++) {
    energies[height_ - 1][col] = this->GetEnergy(height_ - 1, (int)col);
  }

  for (int row = height_ - 2; row >= 0; row--) {
    for (int col = 0; col < width_; col++) {
      int best = 0;
      if (col == 0) { //error occurs here v
        best = FindMinTwo(energies[row + 1][col], energies[row + 1][col + 1]);
      } else if (col == width_ - 1) {
        best = FindMinTwo(energies[row + 1][col - 1], energies[row + 1][col]);
      } else {
        best = FindMinThree(energies[row + 1][col - 1],
                            energies[row + 1][col],
                            energies[row + 1][col + 1]);
      }
      energies[row][col] = this->GetEnergy(row, col) + best;
    }
  }
  return energies;
} // energies is properly deallocated by the function that uses it
```

I've tried changing the ints to unsigned ints, but the error didn't go away. I also should not encounter out-of-bounds access errors, since row starts at `height - 2` and the highest value of row accessed within the loop is `height - 1`.

For some reason, adding a statement which prints every value in the array makes the error go away.

Comment: Dont write code like this with all this dangling `new`s. To allocate arrays at runtime use std::vector<int> (or std::vector<std::vector<int>> for s2D). You are just setting yourself up for memory leaks.  Ever since C++11 was released (with containers) the use of new/delete is no longer recommended (only to be use within datastructures)

Comment: The main warning is about you allocating the arrays but not setting the values to 0 (C++ will not initialize memory by default).  Another good reason to use std::vector. Since you can do `std::vector<int> values(n,0);` to allocate an array of n values with initial value `0`

Comment: Looks like the source you learned C++ from is out of date. Some good resources to learn C++ from are [learncpp.com](https://www.learncpp.com/) for your initial steps (it is very decent for an online tutorial). 
Then use [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) to lookup everything C++ has to offer. 
And finally use the [C++ core guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines) to keep up to date with how C++ evolves and how it is supposed to be used.

Comment: I cannot use std::vector for this project, otherwise I would have. My code also initializes every value to zero already. Did you even read my code?

Comment: I am just reading over your code. In the first appearance of FindMinTwo you hav a loop to iterate the col from 0 to width-1. But you are accessing [col+1]. So if I read your code correctly you will rund in every row into an array out of bounds error... Maybe this will cause your issue.

Comment: @The_Rogue12 I really hate teachers that tell you this! They are not teaching you C++ at all. If it is a datastructures class the should ask you to write your own version of a class that does the memory managment and also tell you to use std::vector ever after. And me bad I missed the initialization ;) When you write your own verion of vector really make sure you remove the copy constructors (or really think hard about what to do if you make a copy). Also when you make your own vector class make sure to write tests for it before using it in the rest of your code.

Comment: If a loop has special cases for the first or last iterations, moving them out of the loop makes the code much clearer.

Comment: @The_Rogue12 *" My code also initializes every value to zero already...."* No **that is not actually initialization**. Initialization happens only once and you're looping through and "assigning" values. There is a difference between the two terms in c++. If you want to do "initialization" you should do `energies[row] = new int[width_]();`. Note the added parentheses `()` in my modified statement. With this you won't have to use the for loop. **Also you may be going out of bounds of the array.**

Comment: @The_Rogue12 Also provide a [mcve]

Comment: *I cannot use std::vector for this project, otherwise I would have.* -- Poor `std::vector` is still being discriminated against, even though it has been officially part of the C++ library for **26 years** now.  Wow.  The same thing with -- *I'm also using different functions instead of std::min because I'm not allowed to import algorithm for this project* -- another quarter-century part of C++ you cannot use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

clang-tidy doesn't make assumptions for you. For example, it doesn't assume that `width_` is greater than 1. And indeed, if `width_ == 1`, you get a bunch of problems and clang-tidy warns about some of them.

Add `assert(width_ > 1)` at the beginning, and the error will go away. Or, if you are not willing to assert that, revise your algorithm to correctly handle the case of `width_ <= 1`.